# Query Data in SQL Server From Android

Tags: android, database, sql-server-2008

I have a small project in connection android and SQL Server.

I don't understand why (java.lang.NullPointerException).

This is my code :

```
try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                Log.e("Profile_show","Error in connection with SQL server");
            } else {
                String query = "select * from DAILY where MADL='" + username  + "'";
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                if(rs.next())
                {
                    Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    datanum.put("A", rs.getString("tendl"));
                    agencyName = datanum.get("A");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Profile_show"," error :"+ex);
        }
```

Ang the Logcat :

```
E/Profile_show:  error :java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Anyone know how to fix my problem?

Thank you

Comment: Does it tell you which line this occurred on? Have you verified that `username` is non-null?

Comment: i toast username it's ok... i think the problem in Map<String, String>

Comment: Could it be `rs` that is null? Have you checked whether or not `rs.next()` executes? I would attach a debugger and inspect the elements, otherwise add a few more log statements and print out each variable to see what could be null.

Comment: Perhaps right before your if statement do `Log.e("Profile_show", "rs value: " + rs);`. If that doesn't print null, perhaps you can also log `rs.getString("tendl");` in each loop.

Comment: it's only show the Log in catch -_- ... i added Log below Result rs

Comment: I would log after each line then and figure out which one is causing it to throw an exception?